# Null Pointer Error When Referencing View in Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

Really simple but just not getting it.
I want to reference a view by ID that is in the `Fragments` XML File that I inflate.

I'm declaring the view.

```
TextView nameView;
```

I'm getting the view from the layout.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trackfrag, group, false);
nameView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.trackName);
```

I get the problem in the below method when it is called from its activity.

```
 public void setTrackDetails (String name, String description) {
    Log.e("TRACKFRAG", "setTrackDetails Called");
    nameView.setText(name);
    Log.e("TRACKFRAG", "setTrackDetails Finished");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**ADDED XML**

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trackName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/anchor"
            android:text="Track Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
```

The `Fragment` loads up and is displayed fine if I don't call this method but I need a way of changing the text in one of the `Text Views`.

**ADDED FRAGMENT CREATION**

```
public void onTrackSelected(String track) {
    Log.e("FRAGTRANS","History List Pressed");

    Fragment trackFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("historytrack");
    if (trackFrag == null) {
        trackFrag = new TrackFragment();
        Log.e("TRACKSEL","new trackfrag created");
    }

    addFragment(trackFrag, true, HISTORYTAG, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);

    ((TrackFragment) trackFrag).setTrackDetails(track,"testing");
}
```

**ADD FRAGMENT METHOD**

```
void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag, int transition) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(transition);
        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: from its activity - it means from its fragment class or its FragmentActivity class

Comment: What is the error in your Logcat? NullPointerException? Show us the trackfrag.xml

Comment: Yea its a NullPointerException I will add the xml up in the original

Comment: Could you give us xml with trackfrag. As far as I can see you just don't have trackName in this layout so after findViewById it is null.

Comment: the xml for the text view i want is above

Comment: And you are putting your textView layout as fragment to activity? Maybe you are using setTrackDetaild in onCreate in activity (when fragment isn't created yet?) or later, before fragments onCreateView is invoked?

Comment: @ania I have included the code I use to present my fragment and call the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in invoking setTrackDetails() method. Please look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) where you can see that:

> Calling commit() does not perform the transaction immediately. Rather, it schedules it to run on the activity's UI thread (the "main" thread) as soon as the thread is able to do so.

So just after you invoke commit your fragment is not created yet or creating is in progress and your nameView isn't set yet.
Best solution would be after creating your fragment(can be after setting nameView because fragment already has activity) invoking method from activity which takes text:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trackfrag, group, false);
nameView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.trackName);
String str = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getTextForLabel();
nameView.setText(str);
```

Please read documentation about fragments and its lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

did you initialize your inflater like this,

```
     inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

check this out.
clean your project and run....

Comment: the inflater is passed in through the create view method so i don't need to initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem.

The code you have mentioned above, just write that part in `onActivityCreated()` method in `Fragment` class. That way I solved the problem.

Comment: how did you access your inflater and viewgroup from that method though?

Comment: i use the same statement that u have used, but I access it by using getActivity() method